# WHERE IN clause display result by them index in IN

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table, just id and name, have a mysql like this

```
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(154,12,148,50);`
```

and i use while loop PHP for display result as normal way :

while($rows= mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $rows['id'], echo $rows['name'] }

but result is ordered by id field in IN clause 12 ,50,148,154

i want to result still them index in IN() : 154,12,148,50

is there any way?

thank alot

Comment: The answer is in the question! See FIELD()

Answer (score 1):

read [FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN(154,12,148,50)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,154,12,148,50)
```